# What is the right construct to replace a static call on Generic Types?

Tags: c#, generics, types, static-methods

I'm trying to create a generic Type Converter.  All types will have a base-class of `Entity`, and an interface of `IConvertable`.  I've implemented an interface for objects that can be converted:

```
public interface IConvertable
{
    public bool CanConvert<TTarget>() where TTarget : Entity, IConvertable
    Tuple<bool, Entity> TryConvertTo<TTarget> where TTarget: Entity, IConvertable
}
```

The idea is that each specific sub-class of Entity (`partial` classes, auto-generated code, I cannot directly modify) will have a `CanConvert<TTarget>`, which will determine if it can be converted to the target type.

I was trying to put together the generic type converter, which will take `IEnumerable`s of `Entity`, transforming them (And performing other tasks at the same time - for instance through other interfaces, reparenting), and then returning the transformed `Entity` classes.

My initial realisation was that, effectively, `CanConvert<TTarget>` is `static`, in that it is always constant from a `TSource` to a `TTarget`, so when I build my converter:

```
public class EntityConverter<TSource, TTarget> where TSource : Entity, IConvertable
                                               where TTarget : Entity, IConvertable
{
    private IEnumerable<TSource> Records { get; set; }

    public EntityConverter(IEnumerable<TSource> records) {
        if (!TSource.CanConvert<TTarget>()) {
            // error condition, reporting, etc.
        }

        Add(records);
    }

    public void Add(IEnumerable<TSource> records) { ... }

    public void Convert() {
        // massively simplified for example - there will actually be a store
        // holding, more functionality, parent-child relationships, but
        // this is the basic principle
        for (var c in convertables) {
            c.TryConvertTo<TTarget>();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, there are many reasons why `static` functions cannot be used on generics (Eric Lipperts excellent descriptions of this are available [on](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/06/14/calling-static-methods-on-type-parameters-is-illegal-part-one/) [his](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/06/18/calling-static-methods-on-type-parameters-is-illegal-part-two/) [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/06/21/calling-static-methods-on-type-parameters-is-illegal-part-three/)), however this leaves me in a quandry - how do I define something that describes the type (Not instance) and can be referenced from the type, in a generic structure, without having massive external `partial` constructs or evil factories - this is supposed to be an extinsible, re-usable structure than someone can call from another class by simply extending the `partial` types with the interface implementation.

I suspect I'm viewing things the wrong way around, but I can't see what.  How can I determine if a type conversion is valid, without having something else in the middle to hold the type conversions?

**edit**
Have updated the code sample a bit (Previously had the conversion in the constructor).  I actually do the conversion quite a bit later on in the process, as I have multiple sources of convertables which need to be added, prior to the actual conversion.  This results in the actual error (If `!CanConvert<TTarget>()`) coming quite far down the line.  For each instantiation of this class, it will be converting from type `TSource` to `TTarget`, so the validity of that conversion should be known in the constructor, and it should error in the constructor, rather than during the conversion later on...  At least, that's my read on things.

Thanks to @Dennis for clarifying some of my thoughts on things... I may end up reconstructing this anyway, but I don't feel I'm far off.  I have thought about putting the `CanConvert<TTarget>()` check inside the `Add()` function... which feels like I'm nearly there...

Comment: What is wrong with just calling `CanConvert` on each instance in `convertables`? That would even be more correct, because some `TBase` may not be convertable to `TSomething`, while `TDerived : TBase` is.

Comment: side note: don't use tuple. `bool TryConvertTo<TTarget>(out Entity result)` is a better design

Comment: Also, I am not sure that passing `convertables` to constructor is a best approach.  That should probably be a method instead. And your notes about other operations ("there will actually be a store
        // holding, more functionality") suggest a possible violation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle by `EntityConverter`. Converter should only convert - that is what its name suggests.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Granted, the conversion is a single princple, however the overall definition of 'convert' in the domain is 'store a list of records, at some point, transform them into new types (What is discussed here), including having to convert them to parent/child relationships based upon other variables, and then submit those to the system'... admittedly, these probably should be broken apart.  I probably need to reconsider some design principles.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, it will be better to move conversion logic into `EntityConverter`s and throw away `IConvertible`? Who should call `EntityConverter`?

Comment: The functionality is complex, but basically:
- CRM Plugin, registered against all entities.
- Constructable code, to register type conversion (loaded dynamically from CRM)
- CanConvert (Static class) gets values from CRM to check if Entity Conversion has been reigstered
- Convert performs the conversion.
- Certain conversions are more complex than basics, so each entity type has the ability to hard-code its conversion, which business rules will see changing semi-regularly.
- Generics used so that plugin conversion can be simplified - do hard work up front, simplify future changes.

Comment: Am I mistaken if you're trying to re-invent the wheel instead of using AutoMapper?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I wasn't aware of that tool, and I'm attempting to do some domain-specific functions later on in the process (Setting parents - EntityReference class properties - based on results of creation process of the new records), as well as handling CRM-specific entities (OptionSet class, EntityReference class, etc.)... If it will handle these, then I can use it and will, indeed, do so...  Thanks.

Comment: @PeterStreet Uhmm... I believe that you should really go the AutoMapper route. It's exactly what you're looking for. Mapping objects to objects, either using conventions or by configuration. Converting or mapping is the same for you.

Comment: @PeterStreet I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, it seems like a task for [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). You want to set properties from an object to other one. That's all.

I would avoid implementing this myself since I doubt you would get what AutoMapper already does in few days or months.

*While I understand that this doesn't answer your question at all, I feel that it's all about finding a good solution rather than over-engineering yours.*

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've had a look at Automapper, and it looks like it does 95% of what I require for the conversion process; the rest can be done in my own code.  As you say, finding a good solution to the problem, even if it's not what was asked, is often better than overengineering a solution that works but is not optimal or harder to maintain.

Comment: @PeterStreet Yeah!! That's it... Some tools aren't taylored like we would do ourselves, but we need to focus on our own domain rather than trying to address all problems in a single project :)

Answer (score 1):

It's too complicated.

There will be enough to keep `TryConvertTo` in `IConvertable`.
Just return `false`, when target type isn't applicable. Yes, this will be the same for all instances, but what's wrong here?

Note, that you're breaking well-known pattern for `Try...` methods, when returning a tuple. IMO, this will be more familiar:

```
public interface IConvertable
{
    bool TryConvertTo<TTarget>(out TTarget entity)
        where TTarget: Entity, IConvertable
}
```

Comment: I'm preparing this code for C#7 with the named-tuple output, which I find much easier to use and operate with than the clumsy and oft-abused 'out' types...  Granted, you're right - the pattern is well known, but that doesn't mean it's right :D  However, I get your point - doing the TryConvertTo without the Constructor limitation will work, potentially...  Thanks.

Comment: @PeterStreet The other alternative is to return some sort of an [`Option<T>`](https://github.com/nlkl/Optional)  value - it avoids both the additional `out` parameter and pre C# 7 tuple issues (nondescriptive property names).

Comment: Question - given that the actual conversion in the final program can be significantly further on from the construction of the method - I was hoping to 'fail early' if non-convertable types were input, prior to performing other operations.  Is there some way of handling this?

Comment: @PeterStreet: that was just a note, not the main point. There are many "wrong", but "usual" things. Think about that, if this will be public API, accessible by number of users.

Comment: @PeterStreet: what do you mean by "construction of the method"? Could you update the question to clarify this?

Comment: @Dennis Updated - thanks for the clarifying questions.